# Difference between LSI SAS3081E-R vs. LSI SAS3081E-S SAS/ATA HBAs

Tags: sata, sas, lsi, hba

I'm trying to figure out if there are any differences between the "R" vs. the "S" of this SAS controller. As far as I can tell, the "S" is a Sun Microsystems re-branded version. I can't find much solid documentation on the "S" version.

Most documentation that I find is on Oracle's documentation website, but mostly it's about setting up RAID on the HBA, not the specs themselves. I know Intel and (apparently) Sun re-brand the controller as their own but I'm curious to know if there are any minor/major differences that Sun may have made.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly the difference, nothing more or less, HP also rebranded the same controller too.

Comment: Had to ask just in case I missed something vital.